# What is the purpose of an bpool partition in ZFS and what does it contain?

Tags: filesystem, zfs

With an installation of Ubuntu-Cinnamon with ZFS as file system, the following partitions are created:

```
/dev/sda1  (efi)
/dev/sda2  (swap)
/dev/sda3  (bpool)
/dev/sda4  (rpool for data)
```

What is the purpose of an bpool partition with ZFS and what does it contain?

Comment: If you run the `df` command, the answer will almost present itself ...

Comment: Artur, your answer, while concise, doesn't help anyone whose system is not working. I'm stuck in the Recover process of upgrading to 23.04. The partitions are not mounted, and I'm trying to figure out whether to wipe zfs' bpool and replace it with ext4, then restore the files that were in bpool into the the ext4 as /boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per this article from Tech Republic about [How to Manage ZFS Pools in Ubuntu 19.10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-manage-zfs-pools-in-ubuntu-19-10/):

> One thing you should understand how to do is the management of your ZFS Pools. ZFS is capable of managing data that spans across devices. ZFS uses virtual storage pools, called zpools. A `zpool` can contain numerous directories. For example, on a Ubuntu Desktop 19.10 installation (with ZFS support added), there are two basic pools:
>
> - `bpool` is the boot pool and stores all boot-related directores
> - `rpool` is the root pool and stores everything under `/` (minus `/boot`)

`bpool` is equivalent to a non-ZFS `/boot` partition containing the kernel images, GRUB bootloader configurations, etc. kept independent from the root disk partition.  (LVM installations create a separate `/boot` partition so that it boots properly from an on-disk partition).  Anything you see in `/boot` when you examine your system filestructure is what's in `bpool`.

Concurrently, `rpool` is where all your data on system resides.  Your installation, your user data, etc. all lives in `rpool`.

(This standard continues despite the article referring to a now-end-of-life release of Ubuntu, because it's still  accurate definitions of both `bpool` and `rpool`)

You can read up about this also in the technical details within the `OpenZFS` documentation on [Ubuntu 22.04 Root on ZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html) for more technical implementation details.

This should also be reflected in the output of `df` on the command line, and should show you which pools are mapped to which directory locations in your filesystem structure on disk.  Namely, that `/boot` is in `bpool`, and `/` (root partition) is in `rpool`.